# Picture Someone Engaging VS Engaged

Tags: participles, deverbal, middle-voice, transitivity

I looked up the word "picture" in the dictionary and it is usually said "Picture someone doing something".
Shouldn't the word "engaged" be "engaging" in the following sentence?

> Perhaps you’re obsessively picturing him **engaged** in drunken coitus
>   with another woman.

This line was said by Sheldon Cooper, who hardly ever makes grammatical mistakes, so I am pretty sure it is grammatically correct what he said, but I don't know why he said "engaged" instead "engaging". Please highlight the difference. Thanks.

Comment: The continuous tense won't make it ungrammatical in *such sentences.* However, here, 'engaged' looks better. What bothers me more is the use of the adjective 'drunken' with that noun following. Never heard "drunken ...." before! Thus, I'd write it: *"Perhaps you are obsessively picturing **him drunken engaged in coitus** with another woman."*

Comment: Is it only correct for the verb "engage"? What if I chose a different verb? "Picturing him having lunch" v's "picturing him had lunch"?

Comment: According to Longman Dictionary, you can say " drunken party/orgy/brawl etc a party etc where people are drunk:
 Tom got into a drunken brawl (=fight) in a bar."

Comment: Strange. Drunken party is okay, but this is new to me. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a special case for 'engage'. That's why I said *in such sentences* as you give examples of '...having lunch' etc.

Answer (score 1):

The reason there is no -ing here is that "engaged" here is used as an adjective, not as a verb in a past tense. It is perfectly fine to say something like "I am engaged now (at this very moment)".

Using the word *engaging* would change the meaning here as it would be a verb that would suggest that the process of engagement is still incomplete. But of course it still would be grammatically correct to use it if that was an intention.

Other examples of such adjectives that look like they are past-tensed verbs would include such words as focused, motivated, moved etc.

Answer (score -1):

'engaged in' in this context means he is in the act of doing it, as opposed to 'engaging in' where he could be just starting

Comment: I have never heard of that. Would it work for other verbs?

Comment: he is submerged in the water --  he is submerging in the water

Comment: or the man is dead --- the man is dying

Comment: "the man is dead --- the man is dying " I don't see how that sentence is related to my sentence? are you saying that "dead" is as "engaged, and "dying" as "engaging" ?

Comment: dead referring to a state (just as engaged in) and dying referring to the road leading to that stage (dying)